# What type of Rice is best for Indian Style Rice Pudding?

Tags: rice, indian-cuisine, pudding

What type of Rice is best for Indian Style Rice Pudding?

Comment: By Indian style rice pudding, do you mean [Kheer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kheer)? (Also called *payas* / *payesh* / *payasam*, depending on region.)

Comment: Arborio rice will probably work - hard to specify when India is such a big place, and has a lot of regional styles.

Answer (score 2):

In Kerala style cuisine (which is what I'm most familiar with as an eater, not a cook) the rice is a **short, white variety that is fried in ghee** first. It's very **similar to the short grain rice used in Japanese** cooking.

I have no idea how this would be packaged in the United States, it's just Rice (for the short grain), or long grain/Basmati rice here. I depend on Indian friends to help me identify the good stuff.

As a cook, I find both the short, white style and plain white basmati work very well. The texture with the short grain rice is smoother, and you can taste more of the milk (or coconut milk) and cardamom. It's also very good served cold. The basmati produces a heartier rice pudding that is enhanced by adding extra raisins and cinnamon. I like this best hot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sona masoori..as the grains are optimum size for the pudding.

Answer (score 1):

You can get away with what in Britain, we call 'pudding rice'. Generally speaking anything short and fat will do.